Vinca not blooming flowers
My vinca is having buds but it is not blooming I water it when the soil is dry also it wilts in little sunlight also the flower that last came it's colours had faded to light pink but the plant actually has bright pink colour

Hi @Shaikh, could you please post pictures of your plant?  Up close of the buds, up close of the leaves, and one further back would be awesome.
